# an issue with an equation devised for the incremental update formula (summation)

Tags: summation, means

I am having an issue going through a step-by-step formulation of the equation devised for the incremental update formula. My algebra is super rusty and I would appreciate some feedback!

In the line 3. I do not get how we brought back the `1/n-1` AFTER using the first constant rule?

[image]

Comment: THe only thing which happened there is that we multiplied by $1 = (n-1)\cdot \dfrac{1}{n-1}$ (assuming $n \geq 2$). Multiplying an expression by $1$ doesn't change anything.

Comment: @peek-a-boo damn - how could I not notice this. Thanks! If you move your comment as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.